# Remove empty child elements in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-3.0

My Input XML is as below,

```
<OUTPUT-AREA><TIME-CD>A</TIME-CD>
    <ID-G>
        <Table-ID-T>
            <AT-ID-T>YYYX</AT-ID-T>
            <AT-ID-T/>
            <AT-ID-T/>
        </Table-ID-T>
    </ID-G>
</OUTPUT-AREA>
```

My Output XML shoule be like,

```
<OUTPUT-AREA>
    <TIME-CD>A</TIME-CD>
    <ID-G>
        <Table-ID-T>
            <AT-ID-T>YYYX</AT-ID-T>
        </Table-ID-T>
    </ID-G>
</OUTPUT-AREA>
```

I want to remove only child elements which have null values. In the above example, I wanted to remove only the `<AT-ID-T>` elements which have null values.
But Table-ID-T or ID-G should not be removed.

And one challenge here is that, suppose if all the child elements have null values, then at least one child element should
remain in the Table or array.

For example, the input XML is

```
<OUTPUT-AREA>
    <TIME-CD>A</TIME-CD>
    <ID-G>
        <Table-ID-T>
            <AT-ID-T/>
            <AT-ID-T/>
            <AT-ID-T/>
        </Table-ID-T>
    </ID-G>
</OUTPUT-AREA>
```

then output should be like,

```
<OUTPUT-AREA>
    <TIME-CD>A</TIME-CD>
    <ID-G>
        <Table-ID-T>
            <AT-ID-T/>
        </Table-ID-T>
    </ID-G>
</OUTPUT-AREA>
```

Please provide me a suitable XSLT which meets the requirement.

Please find below the XSLT which I tried,

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test=".!=''">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
```

On applying above XSLT, all the element which have null values removed. But I need to remove only child elements.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  We are happy to help you with any problems that you are having, but you must show us what you have attempted so far.

Comment: @Matthew Sorry, I agree. I didn't append the XSLT i tried in my initial post. I have now updated the post with my XSLT. Please review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the names of the empty elements (e.g. `AT-ID-T`) you want to remove then use

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Table-ID-T[not(AT-ID-T[normalize-space()])]/AT-ID-T[position() > 1] 
                         | Table-ID-T[AT-ID-T[normalize-space()]]/AT-ID-T[not(normalize-space())]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Example online at http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcX for one input sample and http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcX/2 for the other input sample.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following way and its working:

```
<xsl:template match="node()[.='']"/>

<xsl:template match="Table-ID-T/*[1]">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```